# Why does the amide get priority over the nitro group in the sulfonation of N-(4'-nitro[1,1'-biphenyl]-4-yl)acetamide?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

[image]

An amide group is a moderate activating group and the nitro group is a strong deactivating group. Why did sulfonation occur in the ortho position of amide, when it could have added to the meta position of nitro (circled in red)?

I do understand the part that amide is a moderate activating group and that it favors ortho and para position.

[image]

What about this question? Is the ring on the right deactivated, causing the phenyl to act like a moderate activator for the left ring?

Comment: You're thinking only in terms of *selectivity* (i.e. whether it's ortho,para- or meta-directing), but the *reactivity* aspect (i.e. whether it's activating or deactivating) is equally, if not more important, here. Does it help if I put it this way: the nitro group deactivates *every* position on the ring it's attached to, just that the meta position is deactivated *less* than the others?

Comment: Oh!!!!! Thank you so much!!! So the ring on the right (top) is deactivated, while the left ring is activated.

Comment: Would it be okay if I asked you another question? I edited the post.